# ¿Como espero por el cambio de dato en un onChange en javascript?

Tags: reactjs, usestate, filereader

Estoy trabajando en una práctica en la que intento realizar un mini editor de texto, pero cuando mando la información para que sea cargada en un textarea, el primer intento por llamarlo siempre empieza vacío

Este es el código:

```
function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const getFile = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    showFile(file);
  }
  const showFile = async (file) => {
    console.log(file);
    var leer = new FileReader();
    leer.onload = function(e) {
      var contenido = e.target.result;
      showText(contenido);
    };
    leer.readAsText(file);
  }
  const showText = async (contenido) => {
    var elemento = document.getElementById('editor');
    elemento.innerHTML = contenido;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button>abrir</button>
      <input type="file" id="fileGetter" onChange={getFile}/>
      <div>
      <textarea name="editor" id="editor" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
      <pre id="contenido-archivo"></pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para que el método espere a que haya un archivo en la variable?

Comment: ReactJS no se esta usando de forma correcta, te recomiendo [revisar esta publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499387/como-llamar-una-funcion-solo-cuando-se-presione-click) donde se explican más detalles al respecto. saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he realizado algunas modificaciones. Recuerda que para que React pueda esperar una indicación tuya sería mejor usar un array function en ese sentido *onChange={()=>/Tu funcion/}* sería lo mas adecuado.

Aca te dejo el codigo funcional.

```
function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState();
  const getFile = async (e) => {
    var documento = e.target.files[0];
    setFile(documento);
    showFile(documento);
  };

  const showFile = async (file) => {
    var leer = new FileReader();
    leer.onload = function (e) {
      var contenido = e.target.result;
      showText(contenido);
    };
    leer.readAsText(file);
  };
  const showText = async (contenido) => {
    var elemento = document.getElementById("editor");
    elemento.innerHTML = contenido;
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          showFile(file);
        }}
      >
        abrir
      </button>
      <input type="file" id="fileGetter" onChange={(e) => getFile(e)} />
      <div>
        <textarea name="editor" id="editor" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
        <pre id="contenido-archivo"></pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```